# selecting and styling odd numbered portfolio items using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, jquery-selectors, children

I am attempting to reorder the module header and portfolio image of odd numbered portfolio items. You can view my sandbox [here](https://colouredpencil.alineddesign.com/projects-2/).

I though the below might work, but no dice.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    if ( $( this ).is(".et_pb_portfolio_item:nth-child(2)") ) {
        $(".et_pb_module_header").insertBefore(".et_portfolio_image");
    }
});
```

I can't seem to target just the header and the image of the module, it captures everything.

Comment: don't use 2, use `odd`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `:nth-child(2)`, its only select `2nd` element.

Use `:nth-child(odd)` its selects all odd properties of your block.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.et_pb_portfolio_item:nth-child(odd)').each(function(){
        $(this).find(".et_pb_module_header").insertBefore(".et_portfolio_image");
    });
});
```

For more info visit

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp
https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Comment: I believe for this situation `:nth-child(even)` is more apt.

Comment: yes, you can also do like that !! but OP wants odd situation

Comment: This is close but it takes all of the headers from the page and drops before the image.  I'm thinking I will have to do a query for each separate item (ie for the second, the fourth, and the sixth etc) so it only takes the header from that one item? And yeah, totally said odd - confused myself after so long at the screen :)

Comment: I've also tried   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.et_pb_portfolio_item:nth-of-type(2)').each(function(){
        $(this).find(".et_pb_module_header:nth-of-type(2)").insertBefore(".et_portfolio_image:nth-of-type(2)");
    });
});                                which grabs the title from the second item, then drops it before the image of the second item (YAY) but also before the image on every other item (BOO).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.et_pb_portfolio_item:nth-child(odd)').each(function(){
        $(this).find(".et_pb_module_header").insertBefore(".et_portfolio_image");
    });
});
```

Comment: This is close but it takes all of the headers from the page and drops before the image.  I'm thinking I will have to do a query for each separate item (ie for the second, the fourth, and the sixth etc) so it only takes the header from that one item?